# Spotify Starred playlist API is not available

Tags: android, spotify

I am developing a music App in Android, and I will be loading tracks from Spotify. I need the starred Playlist API from Spotify which I couldn't find, but this API is available for [IOS](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Classes/SPTPlaylistSnapshot.html#//api/name/requestStarredListForUser:withAccessToken:callback:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that particular API is deprecated they have changed the **Starred playlist** to **Saved Tracks API**.Check the below link for Clarification.

[Spotify Starred Playlist Deprecated](https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/39)

Answer (score 1):

If you want playlist access and the methods that come with it, you will have to use the Spotify Web API wrapper for Android. The Android SDK allows you to play songs (granted you sign in with a premium account) but the majority of the functionality hasn't been fully implemented into the SDK yet. Here is a link to the SDK https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-android-sdk/

Here is a few links to different Web API wrappers for Android:

https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java

https://github.com/SiegenthalerSolutions/spotify-web-api-android

https://github.com/kaaes/spotify-web-api-android

The first link has a lot of good code examples for searching songs, manipulating playlists, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am already using third link to access API from Spotify,that particular API(Starred) is available for IOS but i couldn't able to find for Android